# How can I call a shortcode in a shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, pdf.js, wordpress-shortcode, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I wanted to call the following shortcode in the wordpress page editor:

```
[pdfjs-viewer url=/wp-content/uploads/pdfs/[wpcf7_session_id]/vertrag.pdf viewer_width=100% viewer_height=1500px fullscreen=true fullscreen_text='Im Vollbildmodus anschauen' download=true print=true]
```

problem is the shortcode `[wpcf7_session_id]`.

Any chance to call that somehow in the page editor?

Or do I need to call it in the backend in the php files? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Shortcodes do not automatically nest -- you have to call do_shortcode($content) yourself. See the caption_shortcode() example on http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.